# JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'bind'

Tags: javascript, asp.net, internet-explorer

I am getting a javascript error "JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'bind'" unable to find what is causing the error. How can I debig/find out the cause for the issue.. below is the screenshot of the error. I am getting this error some time and sometimes it does not

[image]

Comment: what happens when you click break?

Comment: @Donal when I click Break, it stopping the execution

Comment: ok, In Internet Explorer, go to tool Internet Options and un-check the 'Disable Script Debugging' option. That should allow you to view the line of code that is causing the issue - next time you click Break.

Comment: Disable browser link. And show me some code which might be the source of problem.

Comment: @deostroll after disabling the browser link now I am not getting the error... I don't understand what is causing the error..

Comment: Are you able to view the problematic source code?

Comment: @deostroll not now. I will keep monitoring if I get will post here.

Comment: perhaps issue is with ie8. browser link is a technology that employs web sockets. I don't think ie 8 supports that...so the error. And how come ie 8? What os are you using? This is mostly an issue during debugging.